# How to start server for SQLiPy manually as well as in burp?

Tags: sql-injection, burp-suite

I have recently started using Burp and came across SQLiPy and I am stuck how to use it.

```
 python sqlmapapi.py -s -H <ip> -p <port>
```

Can you please guide me what needs to be entered in the proxy and port.